# Selenium Webdriver wait for the form to load content from ajax call

Tags: html, forms, selenium, webdriver, wait

I have an already populated form, but I have to wait until

```
<form id="HostedPaymentMethodPageForm" name="HostedPaymentMethodPageForm" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="planName" value="test">

    <div class="form-group" id="form-group-creditCardType">
        <div class="form-element" id="form-element-creditCardType">
            <div class="card-image-visa-disabled card-image" id="card-image-container-visa"></div>
            <div class="card-image-mastercard-disabled card-image" id="card-image-container-mastercard"></div>
            <div class="card-image-amex-disabled card-image" id="card-image-container-amex"></div>
            <div class="card-image-discover-disabled card-image" id="card-image-container-discover"></div>
            <input id="input-creditCardType" name="field_creditCardType" type="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <input type="text" name="field_creditCardHolderName" id="creditCardHolderName" value="SugarSyncUser" style="display: none;">

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="field_creditCardNumber" id="creditCardNumber" class="field_input" maxlength="16" size="40" placeholder="Card Number" autocomplete="off">


        <input type="text" name="field_cardSecurityCode" id="creditCardCvv" class="field_input" placeholder="CVV" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off">
        <span class="rollOver" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="<img src='/public/image/cvv_preview.jpg'>" data-placement="left">?</span>
    </div>
    <div id="cardDetails">
        <select name="field_creditCardExpirationMonth" id="creditCardExpirationMonth" class="field_select" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136);">
            <option value="" id="creditCardExpirationMonthValue" class="field_select_value">Month</option>
            <option value="01">01 (Jan)</option>
            <option value="02">02 (Feb)</option>
            <option value="03">03 (Mar)</option>
            <option value="04">04 (Apr)</option>
            <option value="05">05 (May)</option>
            <option value="06">06 (Jun)</option>
            <option value="07">07 (Jul)</option>
            <option value="08">08 (Aug)</option>
            <option value="09">09 (Sep)</option>
            <option value="10">10 (Oct)</option>
            <option value="11">11 (Nov)</option>
            <option value="12">12 (Dec)</option>
        </select>
        <select name="field_creditCardExpirationYear" id="creditCardExpirationYear" class="field_select" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136);">
            <option value="" id="creditCardExpirationYearValue" class="field_select_value">Year</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
            <option value="2019">2019</option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
            <option value="2022">2022</option>
            <option value="2023">2023</option>
            <option value="2024">2024</option>
            <option value="2025">2025</option>
            <option value="2026">2026</option>
            <option value="2027">2027</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="field_creditCardPostalCode" id="creditCardPostalCode" class="field_input" maxlength="10" size="40" placeholder="ZIP Code" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="termsConditions">
        <input type="checkbox" id="agreeTerms" value="1">
        <label for="agreeTerms">I have read and agree to the SugarSync
            <br><a href="/terms" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>
        </label>
        <br>
    </div>

    <input id="submit" class="formBtn disabled" type="submit" value="Complete Signup">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Explicit wait for some specific content. It's not ideal to wait for all the elements. No specific way to check all Ajax elements are loaded or not. Please answer if you are not able to access some specific element using Explicit wait due to Ajax loading.

Comment: Can you give a code example? I have no ideea how to use it

Comment: WebElement element= null;
  boolean notFound= true;
  int numberOfTries= 0;
  while ( notFound && tries < 60 ) 
 {
    numberOfTries += 1;
     try 
     {
      element =  driver.findElement( locator );
      if(element.isDisplayed && element.isClickable)//Desired condition
       {         
      notFound = false; //Element identified
       }
    } 
  catch ( Exception e ) 
    {      
      system.out.println("Exception occured")
      notFound = true;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
WebElement element= null;
  boolean notFound= true;
  int numberOfTries= 0;
  while ( notFound && numberOfTries < 60 ) 
 {
    numberOfTries += 1;
     try 
     {
      element =  driver.findElement( locator );
      if(element.isDisplayed && element.isClickable)//Desired condition
       {         
      notFound = false; //Element identified
       }
    } 
  catch ( Exception e ) 
    {                       
      system.out.println("Exception occured")
      notFound = true;
 }
```